# java.math.BigDecimal to Avro .avdl file

Tags: java, avro, bigdecimal, avro-tools

I'm having trouble writing an Avro schema for java.math.BigDecimal type, I tried the following:

1. Based on Avro official [doc](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/spec.html#Decimal), I know I need to define Logical Types myself to support BigDecimal, but that link gives example only in avsc, I'm trying to figure it out in avdl.
2. Based on Avro [doc](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.6/api/java/org/apache/avro/reflect/package-summary.html) and this [example](https://github.com/apache/avro/blob/master/share/test/schemas/stringables.avdl), I wrote below avdl:

`

```
@namespace("test")
protocol My_Protocol_v1 {

  record BigDecimal {
        @java-class("java.math.BigDecimal") string value;
  }
```

`

But it's not working:
This IDL schema compiles fine and can generate a Java class called BigDecimal, but I cannot really use the generated BigDecimal as java.math.BigDecimal, what's wrong? or How should I do it?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so I emailed Apache Avro dev email list and got a response from Doug Cutting (Thanks a lot Doug).

> I believe this has already been implemented but not yet released.
>
> It was implemented in: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-1847
>
> This is slated to be included in the 1.8.2 release, which should soon be out.

Answer (score 0):

Just to shed some light on how it works in the newer version:
We just started using rc4 of `1.8.2` and you can create BigDecimal fields with the following syntax:

```
record Thing {
    decimal(10,2) foo;
}
```

The `Thing` class will have a `BigDecimal` property `foo` with a precision of 10 and scale of 2.

Answer (score 0):

decimal(10,2) is not generating decimal data type in avsc schema even though compiler version has changed to 1.8.2 version..